# How to find value of any attribute from List of Custom Object using drool and then store it to variable

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, drools

I have a POJO implementation as:

```
public class Product{
String name;
String brand;
String company;
}
```

My problem::

Need to fetch intended Product from worldOfProductList based on name and company(both fields are known so that filter can be applied).
After getting one specific Product from that list then need to store "brand" value into some variable(can be global) for future use.

NOTE:: As of now, getting only a unique Product using that filter.

My approach is something like:

```
[condition][]Get intended Product from list = $productList: java.util.LinkedList() from collect(Products(name="abc",company="com") from worldOfProductList)
```

This statement is working properly and able to get my value in sysout statement as:

```
System.out.println("Brand is "+((Product)($productList.get(0)).getBrand());
```

But I need to use this brand value in DSL and store into variable. I tried below combinations but not succeed.

```
1.[condition][] Store Brand into variable=$brandVar: $productList[0].brand

2.[condition][] Store Brand into variable=Product($brandVar: $productList[0].brand)

3.[condition][] Store Brand into variable=$brandVar: ((Product)$productList.get(0)).getBrand()
```

Comment: Don't start off with a DSL. Design your rules using DRL, and when that works, start creating your DSL.

Comment: @laune, agreed to the approach, but the problem still persist. Not able to get attribute value of an object from the list into other variable.

Comment: Do you, on applying the selection by `name` and `company`, expect only one `brand` value or multiple values? Also, are `Product` objects inserted individually as facts or is there just one container class with a `List<Product>`? - These issues aren't clear enough due to the DSL layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this as 2 separate entries in your DSL, then you can do something like this:

```
[condition][] Store Brand into variable= Product($brandVar: brand) from $productList
```

This will cause an activation of the rule for each different Product you have in `$productList`. In the RHS of the rule you will have access to `$brandVar`.

If you are only interested in the brands and not in the products themselves, then you can also try something like this:

```
[condition][]Get Brands from intended Product from list = $productList: java.util.Set() from accumulate(Products(name="abc",company="com", $brandVar: brand) from worldOfProductList, collectSet($brand))
```

Hope it help,

Comment: It's good to know. Which of the 2 suggestions did you use? Please go ahead and mark the question as answered if you think the answer was helpful.

Comment: Since I can have at most only one brand from the list hence i have used first approach.